How to get ordered path list from image?
We have got image 100x100 pixels. In this image red line is a path. When i parse this image to pixel colors i get red pixel in random order (in fact i get pixels from image line by line from top to bottom). But i want get a list of ordered dots of the path from point A to point B. How to do it.
example of path in image
This function gets pixel with red color (python language):
def getRoad(imgPng) -> list:
    img = Image.open(imgPng)
    pix = img.load()
    width, height = img.size

    x = 0
    y = 0
    road = []

    for y in range(BORDER_OFFSET, height-BORDER_OFFSET, STEP):
        for x in range(BORDER_OFFSET, width-BORDER_OFFSET, STEP):
            color = pix[x, y]
            if (COLOR_ROAD[0]-7 <= color[0] <= COLOR_ROAD[0]+7 and 
            COLOR_ROAD[1]-7 <= color[1] <= COLOR_ROAD[1]+7 and
            COLOR_ROAD[2]-7 <= color[2] <= COLOR_ROAD[2]+7):
                road.append((x, y))

    # print(len(road))
    return road


Check piecewise segmentation (https://github.com/chasmani/piecewise-regression). This method will return the break points. Then you'll have a list of 9 points. each point refers to breaking point on graph. And you can describe the line between them...

You can also get the contour of the path wiht cv2.findContours()which will have the ordered points. Still the @MSH method is better.

You can extract and order the red path in an image by first collecting all red pixels and then sorting them based on their proximity to each other. The code below demonstrates how to achieve this in Python using the PIL library for image processing and a simple distance-based ordering algorithm.
from PIL import Image
import math

def get_road(imgPng):
    img = Image.open(imgPng)
    pix = img.load()
    width, height = img.size

    road = []
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            color = pix[x, y]
            if (230 <= color[0] <= 255 and 0 <= color[1] <= 50 and 0 <= color[2] <= 50):
                road.append((x, y))

    return road

def distance(point1, point2):
    return math.sqrt((point1[0] - point2[0]) ** 2 + (point1[1] - point2[1]) ** 2)

def order_points(points, max_jump=50):
    ordered = [points.pop(0)]
    while points:
        last = ordered[-1]
        next_point = min(points, key=lambda point: distance(last, point))
        if distance(last, next_point) > max_jump:
            break
        points.remove(next_point)
        ordered.append(next_point)
    return ordered

road_points = get_road('./image.png')
ordered_road_points = order_points(road_points)

print(ordered_road_points)

